# How to show that this class is a topology in X?

Tags: general-topology

is this proof correct? can I answer this way? I have improved the answer, If not, what is the correct way?

Let X be a nonempty set, Y be a topological space with topology $ \Gamma $ and $ f : f \to Y$ A surjective function. Prove that the Class $ \Psi f^{-1} (U) : U \in \Gamma $ is a topology in X

That's right? If it is not well demonstrated, thank you for helping me to demonstrate it correctly

Solución:

1. $ \ X \in \Psi$ but for being $ \Gamma $ topology un $ Y, \emptyset, Y \in \Gamma$ And $ f ^{-1}(Y)= X, ~ f ^{-1} ( \emptyset )= \emptyset$
   if  $  \{U_i \}  \subset{} \Psi $ then   $  \displaystyle\bigcup_{i} U_i \in \Psi$
   taking into account that:

$ f^{-1} \ ( \bigcup_{i} U_i ) = \bigcup_i f ^{-1} \ ( U_i) $ .

if $ U, V \in \Psi $ then $ U \cap{} V \in \Psi$

Consequently $ f^{-1} \ ( U \cap{} V ) = f^{-1} \ (U) \cap{} f^{-1} \ (V) $

Comment: It's correct provided you are convinced that the inverse of a function on subsets respects finite intersections and arbitrary unions.

Comment: is there a better way to prove it? how would it be? Thanks ver y much

Comment: No no, it's fine. Do you see why $f^{-1}(\bigcup_i U_i)=\bigcup_i f^{-1}(U_i)$?

Comment: thanks, very  much

Comment: can I complement it? how would it be? thanks for your attention

Comment: Or is it more than enough to answer like this?

Comment: Add more words and explanations. This is just a collection of formulae, not a proof. A proof has a clear structure. This lacks that.